# Ambient Isotopy

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds, surfaces, knot-theory

From Hirsch's Differential Topology, p. 180.

The first of the isotopy extension theorems says;

> Let $A\subset M$ be a compact submanifold and $F:V\times I \rightarrow S^{3}$ an isotopy of $A$. If either $F(V\times I) \subset \delta M$  or $F(V\times I) \subset M - \delta M$, then $F$ extends to a diffeotopy of $M$ having compact support.

What I don't understand is why this does not imply that every isotopy of knots is automatically an ambient isotopy. Since knots are compact and $S^{3}$ has no boundary.

Please help, very confused!

Comment: Hatcher's *Differential Topology* ??  What's that?  FYI, it does imply isotopic knots are ambient isotopic, that's the point.    Perhaps you mean a book by Milnor or Guillemin and Pollack by a similar name?

Comment: Sorry, the book's by Morris Hirsch.

Comment: A remark that might be helpful: for smooth knots, ambient isotopy and isotopy are the same. However in the topological category, these notions differ. For example, you could pull a trefoil tight until the knotted part vanishes to a point. This is a topological isotopy, but not a smooth isotopy.